# Issue with module in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following service which uses a factory called *newsFactory*. And inside this factory,I have a json array.

**services.js**

```
        'use strict';

        angular.module('larissaApp')
               .factory('newsFactory',function(){

                    var newsfac = {};

                    var news = [
                        {
                            _id: 0,
                            title: 'Camping in the City and this year',
                            image:'img/news1',
                            label: '',
                            description: '...',
                            comments: ''
                        },
                        {
                            _id: 1,
                            title: 'International Museum Day 18 May 2017',
                            image:'img/news2',
                            label: '',
                            description: '... ',
                            comments: ''
                        }
                    ]

                    newsfac.getNews = function(){
                        return news;
                    }

                    newsfac.getNewsIndex = function(index){
                        return news[index];
                    }

                    return newsfac;
        });
```

Next I declared a controller called IndexController. And there I am calling the getNews() function defined in my factory that was created in services.js.

**controllers.js**

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('larissaApp')
           .controller('IndexController',
   ['$scope','newsFactory',function($scope,newsFactory){
                 $scope.news = newsFactory.getNews();  
    }]);
```

And finally I want to display all the objects of the json array as a list. So for that I am using the following piece of code.

**index.html**

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="IndexController">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                   <h2>News</h2>
                   <ul class="media-list">
                       <li class="media" ng-repeat="newsArticle in news">
                           <div class="media-left media-middle">
                               <a>
                                   <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                                        ng-src={{newsArticle.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                               </a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="media-body">
                               <h2 class="media-heading">{{newsArticle.title}}</h2>

                           </div>
                       </li>
                   </ul>

                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                    <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                </div>
 </div>
```

When I am running my index.html file I get this error in the console.

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=larissaApp
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:2262
at b (angular.js:2183)
at Object.module (angular.js:2260)
at services.js:3

angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=larissaApp
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:2262
at b (angular.js:2183)
at Object.module (angular.js:2260)
at controllers.js:3
```

From my research I found out that the module name is not loaded or it is misspelled. I don't get this. My module in both services.js and contollers.js is defined as *larissaApp*. Plus I am importing those files

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
```

Comment: `angular.module('larissaApp')` is a getter of an **existing** module, so if this is the first time you declare it, change it to `angular.module('larissaApp', [])` (And then use the `angular.module('larissaApp')` for the next time you need to bind things to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct below things:

1. Define `ng-app="larissaApp"` in your html, if not already.
2. You need to correct your module declaration by defining `empty dependency` array. like : `angular.module('larissaApp',[])` for the first time.

See this working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/og9sq8r1/)

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

In given code snippet, I don't see that you have defined  `larissaApp` anywhere, I can see you are trying to use it. You need to define 
`angular.module('larissaApp',[])` either in a separate module or in your controller or services. Pay attention to `[]` without a function this is a way of defining module and angular.module('larissaApp') is a way of using module. You can inject your module dependency under [].

Answer (score 0):

You have to also load your **larissaApp** module in HTML using **ng-app** and you can do that as follow :

`<div class="row row-content" ng-app="larissaApp" ng-controller="IndexController">`